# Fantasy story with a tree and children

Tags: story-identification

I have hesitated putting this on here as I have so few details but here goes.

I was read this story in infant school in the mid 80's.

- The story has children in it at least 1 boy and 1 girl these may be
  siblings.
- They find a tree with a door in it not at the base but
  half way up.
- The tree is in some woods near a house.
- They manage
  to get through the door.....  and that's where my memory goes blank
  grrr.

The story had a very fantasy feel to it and I remember the book been large and thick so it might of been in a book with several stories. It was definitely hardback.  I don't remember the cover unfortunately.

Comment: The "magic far away tree" by Enid Blyton?

Comment: I am Groot. I Am Groot.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214022/90s-book-about-children-climbing-a-tree-and-visiting-different-worlds-from-ther (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it had a door to different lands in the branches, which 'rotated', it could be 'The Magic Faraway tree'.

I could NOT put it down as a kid.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Faraway_Tree_%28novel%29

Answer (score 19):

Echoing my earlier comment, it could be "[The Magic Faraway Tree](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/74998.The_Magic_Faraway_Tree)" by Enid Blyton.

The main characters are a set of male and female siblings. They discover a tree in a magical woodland. The tree has a series of doors set at differing heights:

> [once they're further up the faraway tree] At this moment the yellow door opened and a small fairy looked out. Her hair was fluffed out around her shoulders, drying, and she was rubbing it with a towel. She stared at the peeping children.
>
> 'Did you ring my bell,' she asked, 'What do you want?'
>   'We just wanted to see who lived in the funny little tree-house,' said Joe, peering in at the dark room inside the tree. The fairy smiled. She had a very sweet face.
>
> 'Come in for a moment,' she said, 'My name is Silky, because of my silky hair. Where are you off to?'
>   'We are climbing the Faraway Tree to see what is at the top,' said Joe.

Comment: It certainly sounds like it I will try and grab a copy to confirm